# Where to find information on unfinished tasks in Spark UI?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-ui

So today I came across a situation like this:

[image]

I can easily find an information on completed tasks but where can I find any info on those 2 tasks that haven't been completed yet?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: stderr logs of executors that run these tasks is one place...